# Why does JSON.parse() add numbers in front of elements?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string where I build my build my "json-like" format, like

```
_toBeFormated = 
[
    {"foor":"bar","foo":"bar","foo":["bar,bar"]},
    {"foor":"bar","foo":"bar","foo":["bar,bar"]},
    {"foor":"bar","foo":"bar","foo":["bar,bar"]}
]
```

But after calling `JSON.parse` like `_afterFormat = JSON.parse(_toBeFormated)`, my structure looks like the following:

```
_afterFormat =
    0:{"foor":"bar","foo":"bar","foo":["bar,bar"]},
    1:{"foor":"bar","foo":"bar","foo":["bar,bar"]},
    2:{"foor":"bar","foo":"bar","foo":["bar,bar"]}
```

If I try to change to JSON Format at the beginning, like leaving out [ ], if failes to parse, also it looks like valid `JSON` to me. What am I missing, or why does it add the numbers at the beginning?

Comment: How are you reading the structure? Show us your code.

Comment: That's because when you use `[]` it means an array of JSON. The numbers signify the index.

Comment: It's unclear what we're looking at here. That first snippet isn't JSON, it's *Javascript*. That doesn't need to be parsed as JSON anymore. That second snippet is nothing valid. How do you obtain that output exactly?

Comment: If you're talking about its output in the Webkit or Blink console, its just the browser adding index for display purposes, not `JSON.parse()` doing anything funky

Comment: thanks, that made it clear for me @comu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't add numbers. The data structure is an array. The tool you are using to look at the array is showing the index of each entry.